# Do attachments have the same storage and transaction cost rules as resources themselves?

Tags: onflow-cadence

We are implementing a field that may sometimes get big in specific admin-controlled occasions and are evaluating using the new Cadence [`attachments`](https://developers.flow.com/cadence/language/attachments) feature to define that field vs having the field on the `resource` itself. Do `attachements` have the same storage and [transaction cost](https://developers.flow.com/learn/concepts/variable-transaction-fees#execution-costs) rules as `resources`?

Have not used attachments yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, attachments can be thought of as a nested structs/resources, so have the same storage and transaction costs as a field that was explicitly defined in the base type.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an attachment has to be done in a transaction so it has the same rules.